# Rails - using .new() vs .create() methods when defining create action

Tags: ruby-on-rails

When defining the create action in a controller what is the difference between using these two methods.

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(name: item_params[:name])
  @item.save
end
```

vs

```
def create
  @item = Item.create(name: item_params[:name])
end
```

Is one better than another?

Comment: @danielrsmith Your life would be easier if you would actually vote for closing instead of adding a manual comment. And the question could actually be marked as a duplicate...

Comment: @HolgerJust I did, SO added the comment automatically.

Comment: Actually @HolgerJust, vote to close is at 3000 points, I'm 300ish short.

Comment: @danielrsmith In that case, go ahead :)

Answer (score 4):

The new method will return a new object while create will return the object and save it to the database. Using the new method, an object can be instantiated without being saved. From [Active Record Basics](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_basics.html)

Answer (score 0):

New instantiates the item in memory.  Create persists it in the DB.

Say you're creating a new record, when you load up the form, you are `new`ing that record in memory.  Then when you've completed the form, you are `create`ing it and saving it in DB.

Answer (score -1):

if you need just create object use:

```
def create
  @item = Item.create(name: item_params[:name])
end
```

it's smaller and more readable, but

if you have condition in action use first:

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(name: item_params[:name])
  if @item.save
    redirect_to ...
  else
    render:new
  end
end
```

also you can first check if your object is valid. In this case if object invalid transaction (DB connection) won't be opened at all.

```
def create
  @item = Item.new(name: item_params[:name])
  if @item.valid? && @item.save
    redirect_to ...
  else
    render:new
  end
end
```